# Is OOP supported in ATS?

Tags: ats

Basically, I would like to learn whether there is some form of object-oriented programming supported in ATS. If there is, please point me to some examples involving OOP in ATS.

Answer (score 0):

[OOP was directly supported in the earliest version of ATS (ATS/Proto) but that support has been dropped since](https://sourceforge.net/p/ats-lang/mailman/message/25414285/).